# Is connectionWithRequest synchronous?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I wanted to know whether doing:

```
+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate
```

is synchronous or not? doesn't really say in the docs

If it is synchronous then how do I make it async?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Asynchronous -

Look at [NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under Tasks - > Loading Data Asynchronously -> 
`+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:` first method in that list

Answer (score 0):

check out this

documentaion(sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:):

[sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:)

documentaion(sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler):

[sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:)